# How to move a rectangle in Java?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I am trying to move a rectangle but I am not sure how to do it, I know it something to do with 'mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` but don't know how to use it. This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MovRect extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
Color color = Color.green;
int x=30,y=30,w=150,l=150;
String MouseMotion ="";

public void init()
{
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(color);
    g.drawRect(x, y, w, l);

}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    String clickDesc;
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
        clickDesc = "double";
    else
        clickDesc = "single";

    System.out.println("Mouse was " + clickDesc + "-clicked at location (" +
        e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");

        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();

    if( mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+w && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+l )
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
        this.repaint();
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("mouse is being dragged at location (" + e.getX() + ", " +      e.getY() + ")");
    MouseMotion ="mouseDragged";
    repaint();
}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("mouse is being moved at location (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
    MouseMotion ="mouseMoved";
    repaint();
}


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
 }
```

Comment: When do you want the rectangle to move, and where do you want to move it to?
Not sure why you are stud, you have created a program which draws a rectangle with specified x and y. You also listen to mouse movement and mouse clicks and log the mouse x and y position when the mouse moves or when it is clicked. The program is even prepared to repaint should you change the x or y of the box.
Have you not written this program yourself? Which part of it is it that you do not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New answer**
If you want to be able to click and drag the rectangle you just basically update the x and y of the rectangle and have a mouse listener change those values to the mouses current position on click.

**Old Answer**

> Your question is a little confusing. You mention using
>   `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` yet that hasing nothing to do with
>   actually moving the rectangle that deals with a event where the mouse
>   is clicked.
>
> If you just want to move your rectangle you could have a variable and
>   add to the x or y. For Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 100;
> int y = 100;    
> g.fillRect(x,y,100,100);
> ```
>
> Then in your public void run you could do:
>
> ```
>       try
>       {
>         Thread.sleep(100);
>       }catch(Exception e)
>       {
>       }
>       x = x + 2;
>       y = y +2;
>       repaint();
> ```
>
> Or for if the mouse was clicked basically you'd be using the mouse
>   event and when it's clicked you would just set that x and y to the
>   mouse's position.

Comment: He wants to be able to dragged the mouse around and have the square move with it, where did you get triangle from...

Comment: Ooops for some reason typed triangle I meant rectangle. I will edit my message.

Comment: No problem! Basically you just want to use the mouse listener and whenever it's clicked you want it to keep moving to the position of mouse. When clicked again have it stop doing that. Or I guess when you release click it would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the mouse listener to the object you want to listen. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html it will get you started on how to set up the mouse listener.
Also where are you actually stuck? Getting the listener to work? Or getting the rectangle to move?

Comment: i am stuck on getting the rectangle to move

Comment: Do you want to be able to drag it? Or just click and have it move?

Comment: Check out this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Imagewithmousedragandmoveevent.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to 'paint' rectangles this snipet works nicely.

```
public int XVal = 0 , YVal = 0;

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.fillRect(XVal, YVal, 20, 20);

    addMouseMotionListener(
            new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                    XVal = e.getX();
                    YVal = e.getY();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have it move sequentially, you need to get the relative position which is always
currentPosition - LastPosition. You could store the current position using mouseMove.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
  _relativePosition.x = e.getX() - _currentPosition.x;
  _relativePosition.y = e.getX() - _currentPosition.y;
  _currentPosition.x = e.getX();
  _currentPosition.y = e.getY();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to increase the x or y variable in a tick method();